# Team Sprint in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template, tfs-2010

In Team Foundation Server 2010, I have to create a Team Sprint and a Sprint. I don't understand the difference between the two.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the appropriate website to ask this question since it doesn't to involve programming (at least not directly). Perhaps you should try the programmers.stackexchange.com website

Comment: Where did you get the terms "Team Sprint" vs "Sprint".  In TFS 2010 there is an iteration hierarchy where you can structure your iterations.  But I don't know what you mean by Team Sprint, I don't believe thats a TFS 2010 concept.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Ewald Hofman - you see sprint and team sprint because of the process template you have chosen. In your case, I guess it is [Scrum for Team System](http://scrumforteamsystem.codeplex.com/).

The difference between Sprint and Team sprint can be explained as

1. A **Project/Product** has several **Releases**.
2. A **Release** include several **swim lanes** (different areas of project/product)
3. Each **Swim Lane** may have several **Sprints**
4. Each **Sprint** may have **several teams** working on the features. So each team creates **Team Sprint** to group their work items.

[Here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/crispinparker/archive/2010/05/18/getting-started-with-scrum-for-team-system-version-3-tfs-2010.aspx) is a very good article explaining this in detail (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123202852/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/crispinparker/archive/2010/05/18/getting-started-with-scrum-for-team-system-version-3-tfs-2010.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You don't create the Team Sprint and Sprint because of Team Foundation Server 2010, but because of the Process Template you have chosen. If you choose the Scrum template, then you get a Sprint work item, but not the Team Sprint work item. All other process template don't have a Sprint nor team Sprint work item.

So let me know if you are talking about creating work items, and where you see the Team Sprint work item. It is possible that somebody else in your organization created the Team Sprint work item type.